# Open gallery on imageview click

Tags: android, url, gallery, imageview

I am trying to make my program to open the gallery, when I click on an image in my program. The only thing that is really confusing is how to load the image into the gallery, if the image is from the web. Right now i am just making a drawable from URL. Is there a way to start the gallery intent and pass it the url or even a drawable to show the image?

Answer (score 1):

I think  [Android Gallery With Remote Images](http://www.anddev.org/gallery_with_remote_images-t769.html) is what you need.

Comment: That is a good tutorial, but im just looking for a way to start an the intent for gallery, or even astro image gallery when the image is clicked and load the drawable to it. The closest example I can give to this is the facebook app, when you click on an image that someone has posted, it opens it in gallery.